# What is the difference between Agile Modeling and the Agile Manifesto?

Tags: agile, development-methodologies

By searching for the different software development methods I found that there are two AM:

- [Agile Modeling](http://www.agilemodeling.com/)
- [Agile Manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/iso/en/)

The problem is that I can't get the difference between them. If one is a part of another? or an update to the other?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here ? well Yannis have do it, and he deserve a big thanks not like the down voters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Agile Modeling is](http://www.agilemodeling.com/faq.htm#WhatIsAM):

> Agile Modeling (AM) is a practice-based methodology for effective modeling and documentation of software-based systems.  Simply put, Agile Modeling (AM) is a collection of values, principles, and practices for modeling software that can be applied on a software development project in an effective and light-weight manner.  The secret to AM isn’t the modeling techniques themselves -- such as use case models, class models, data models, or user interface models -- but how they’re applied. You may take an agile modeling approach to requirements, analysis, architecture, and design.

While the [Agile Manifesto is](http://www.agilealliance.org/the-alliance/the-agile-manifesto/):

> The Agile Manifesto was written in February of 2001, at a summit of seventeen independent-minded practitioners of several programming methodologies. The participants didn't agree about much, but they found consensus around four main values.

The [four main values being](http://agilemanifesto.org/iso/en/):

> Individuals and interactions over processes and tools
>
> Working software over comprehensive documentation
>
> Customer collaboration over contract negotiation
>
> Responding to change over following a plan

Agile software development is a group of similar methodologies, some of the [more popular ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development#Agile_methods) are:

> - Agile Modeling
> - Agile Unified Process (AUP)
> - Crystal Clear
> - Dynamic Systems Development Method (DSDM)
> - Essential Unified Process (EssUP)
> - Exia Process (ExP)
> - Extreme Programming (XP)
> - Feature Driven Development (FDD)
> - Kanban (development)
> - Open Unified Process (OpenUP)
> - Scrum
> - Velocity tracking

To summarize:

- Agile Modeling is one of the various agile methodologies,
- The Agile Manifesto is the document that introduced the term "agile" and the core values of agile software development.